# one-to-one fluent nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Is it possible yet to do a one-to-one mapping with fluent nhibernate? I have the following as part of an hbm that I'm trying to convert to fluent:

```
    <one-to-one name="Person" property-ref="FileData" constrained="true"/>
```

I see a `OneToOnePart<OTHER>` in the code but i'm not sure how or if this is used to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a HasOne mapping

```
map => map.HasOne(x => x.Person)
     .PropertyRef(x => x.FileData)
     .Constrained();
```

I think that's what you're looking for.